# Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
 
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBOK7x5N5UnjY4TDqndzH7l5tvdNIsWFRc",
  authDomain: "todo-app-e3cf0.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "todo-app-e3cf0",
  storageBucket: "todo-app-e3cf0.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "940016886081",
  appId: "1:940016886081:web:91686613f16b1b1f8001c0",
  measurementId: "G-JHPC7TP12K"
};
  
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
  
export default db;
```

**Error**
Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package C:\Users\Sairam\Visual Code\todo-list\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in C:\Users\Sairam\Visual Code\todo-list\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
Did you mean './firebase'?

Answer (score 67):

I believe the firebase had lot of updates recently, so you should update the imports this way and it worked liked a charm.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBOK7x5N5UnjY4TDqndzH7l5tvdNIsWFRc",
  authDomain: "todo-app-e3cf0.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "todo-app-e3cf0",
  storageBucket: "todo-app-e3cf0.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "940016886081",
  appId: "1:940016886081:web:91686613f16b1b1f8001c0",
  measurementId: "G-JHPC7TP12K"
};

// Use this to initialize the firebase App
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Use these for db & auth
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { auth, db };
```

Comment: yes this is working for me. Thank you for your answer. I didn't use  import 'firebase/compat/firestore'.

Comment: I also had to add:

import 'firebase/compat/storage';

since I am using firebase storage as well.

Answer (score 14):

If you use electron-react-boilerplate, in `webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.ts`, remove firebase from the entry point. For example:

```
  entry: {
    renderer: Object.keys(dependencies || {}).filter((it) => it !== 'firebase'),
  },
```

Comment: Bonus for stating the exact file to modify instead of just saying add a webpack setting.  Worked fo me.

Comment: I had this ERROR in dll renderer renderer[26]
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-firebase-hooks' so I changed your line into ```renderer: Object.keys(dependencies || {}).filter((it) => !it.includes('firebase'))``` and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 9):

In your Firebase config file, set up Firebase as follows:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const config = {
  //your config json file
};


firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const firestore = firebase.firestore();


export default firebase;
```

In the relevant .js script import Firestore and Firebase as follows:

```js
import {firestore as db}  from './firebase-config' 
import firebase from './firebase-config';
```

Comment: This line was crucial for mine to work in Angular. Thank you!

`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';`

Answer (score 7):

You should import like below. I see this from the firebase documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBOK7x5N5UnjY4TDqndzH7l5tvdNIsWFRc",
  authDomain: "todo-app-e3cf0.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "todo-app-e3cf0",
  storageBucket: "todo-app-e3cf0.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "940016886081",
  appId: "1:940016886081:web:91686613f16b1b1f8001c0",
  measurementId: "G-JHPC7TP12K"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

export default db;
```

Comment: my screen goes blank with this. idk what it means!

Answer (score 3):

It is not working because you are using Firebase version-8 codes in upgraded Firebase version-9 , so if you want to solve your problem you should install Firebase version-8 by using the code below:

npm i firebase@8.2.3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that I was importing my firebase.ts config file as `import db from "firebase"` (absolute imports)

The issue here was that webpack was referencing the `"firebase"` from node_modules, rather than from my firebase.ts. And that's why it threw that error.

I fixed it by importing my firebase configs as `import db from "../../firebase"`, and that worked

Answer (score 0):

You have mistaken at `const db = firebase.firestore();`

It should be `const db = firebaseApp.firestore();`

Even after doing that you will get error of module not found. You need to import as following

`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';`

`import 'firebase/compat/firestore';`

This worked for me as I had the same issue!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe i meeted the same problem when using webpack.
i solved the problem by setting  [webpack/configuration/resolve/#resolveconditionnames](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveconditionnames)

Answer (score 0):

As in v-9.8.2. Here is the docs [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firebaseAuth = getAuth(app);
export const fbDatabase = getDatabase(app);
export const fStore = getFirestore(app);
export const fStorage = getStorage(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Firebase provides two Web SDK variants. So make sure that you are using the correct version of firebase library. With version 9 firebase library was arranged independent libraries. Your syntax is using firebase version 8.
[version-8](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more?authuser=0&hl=en#web-version-8) [version-9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more?authuser=0&hl=en#web-version-9)