# Firebase not getting imported in my React JS project/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to use firebase inside my project but the classes related to firebase are not getting imported.

This is what I did till now:

1. Created a new project in firebase console
2. ran the commands, `npm install -g firebase-tools`, `npm install firebase-admin --save` and `npm install --save firebase`
3. Created a new file called `firebase.js` in my project and added the following code:

   ```
   import firebase from "firebase"

   // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
   const firebaseConfig = {
       apiKey: "AIzaSyAdjdq8JsRSWKeHQYCHNzXm8nn29cOh-4s",
       authDomain: "ig-reels-a9b15.firebaseapp.com",
       projectId: "ig-reels-a9b15",
       storageBucket: "ig-reels-a9b15.appspot.com",
       messagingSenderId: "1018616208158",
       appId: "1:1018616208158:web:bb1026f5301bd9294e070f",
       measurementId: "G-W3051LNHFL"
     };

     const firebaseApp = firebase.initializaApp(firebaseConfig)
     const db = firebaseApp.firestore()

     export default db
   ```

I am using `db` variable to pull out data from the cloud firestore database like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import './App.css';
import VideoCard from './VideoCard';
import db from "./firebase";

function App() {
  const [reels, setReels] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("reels").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot.docs.toString())
      setReels(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    })
  }, [])
```

Whenever I run this code I get the following error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 3:0-32

Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\reactjs-practise\reels_clone\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\reactjs-practise\reels_clone\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
Did you mean './firebase'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\Users\Aditya\Documents\reactjs-practise\reels_clone\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.
```

I have successfully installed all the firebase related tools. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Have you checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/70445014/13130697 ?

Comment: The import error has been resolved but nothing is getting rendered on screen. Even the `dataSnapshots` is not getting logged

Answer (score 0):

First, install firebase then You want to create your own firebase.js file. I am give you the example of

firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "apiKey",
authDomain: "authDomain",
projectId: "projectId",
storageBucket: "storageBucket",
messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
appId: "appid"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

App.js

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
//write you own code
```

Comment: I think the imports are wrong. These imports worked for me
`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';`
`import 'firebase/compat/auth';`
`import 'firebase/compat/firestore';`

Comment: okay. Is work for you?

Comment: Yes it's working for me